# ROS Answers SE migration: チュートリアルについて

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

チュートリアルの初級編を進めているのですが、チュートリアル14番のコードをbuildするとエラーがでてしまいます。
以下です。

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:186 (message):
  catkin_package() the catkin package 'message_runtime' has been
  find_package()-ed but is not listed as a build dependency in the
  package.xml
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:89 (catkin_package)
```

runtimeの依存性は、cmakelistに記述しているのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。msg,srvのチュートリアルを参考にしてもよく分かりません。よろしくお願いします。

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195296/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/) by [Kuniaki Saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/20511/kuniaki-saito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error message points out what's missing:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:186 (message):
  catkin_package() the catkin package 'message_runtime' has been
  find_package()-ed but is not listed as a build dependency in the
  package.xml
```

So add `message_runtime` as a dependency in `package.xml`, as in [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg) (that is a few session back from where you're at now):

```
Open package.xml, and make sure these two lines are in it and uncommented:

  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Appending on @130s answer:

In package.xml you need the lines:

```
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

In CMakeLists.txt you need:

```
find_package( catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS message_generation <.... other packages.....> ) 
# note: no message_runtime in find_package
```

And please note that this Q&A forums language should be English. This assures that all people knowing how to solve your issue can understand you question and post an answer...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2